# I need to run a 32 bit version of Firefox but can't find a 32 bit version libgtk-3.so

Tags: firefox, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have unwound the 32 bit pkg for firefox but when I run I get: XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /opt/firefox/libmozgtk.so:
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.

This library exists on my system but only in 64 bit form and I can't find a 32 bit version anywhere. I have a massive number of 32 bit libraries in /usr/lib32 but only show libgtk2 in that directory. The issue is I need a firefox that can run the Java Applets in Oracle Waveset.

Comment: Most basic detail needed is for what OS/release, as packages are built for specific releases (*so API/ABI's align and you don't get segfaults*).

Comment: Ubuntu does not support 32 bit (i386) hardware anymore. What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need 32 bit Firefox?

Comment: As I said in the original post Oracle Waveset is no longer supported but has many of its configurator applications coded as Java applets. Currently I can only run an old IE browser on Windows 7 to administer our server. The security group in my organization is trying to get rid of Windows 7 on user's desktops. I have held them off by converting my Windows 7 box with P to V standalone converter and installed Ubuntu Jellyfish. Now I'd like to have a browser that runs Java applets directly on Jellyfish